# SQL two tables and creating a link table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, relational-database, relational

I have two tables: Employee (ID, Name, Address) and Store(ID,Address) and I would like to record information about people who work in each store.

I thought of making a new table called Employee_List table. My questions:

1- Employee_List and Employee has one-to-many relation, right?

2- Employee_list to store has one-to-one relation, right?

3- How to define foreign and primary keys for Employee_List table?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just add an attribute worksIn to employee? The attribute values of worksIn are store_id values then. worksIn is a foreign key on store(store_id).

Comment: Unless an employee works in more than one store, what @muehlbau said, just add column store_id to employee

Comment: True @popnoodles. If an employee can work in more than one store than create a new relation works_in(employee_id,store_id) with primary key(employee_id,store_id) and foreign key on employee(employee_id) and store(store_id).

Comment: some employees (i.e. managers) work in more than one store.

Comment: @Sam - the solution I provided allows for multiple employees in more than one store.  I have gave my answer using using SQL Server, is that the RDMS you are using?

Comment: @DarrenDavies Yes it is

Comment: @Sam - check out my answer it should help.

Comment: @DarrenDavies just one question, since employee_list to employee has one-to-many relation, is it necessary to add a foreign key to employee for employee_list?

Comment: @Sam - yes, the foreign key will ensure referential integrity. For example, the value Employee_Id in Employee_List is a valid Employee.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Employee_list should have:

- employee_listid (INT PK)
- employee_id (INT FK)
- store_id (INT FK)

I would recommend changing the table name to represent the composite table, i.e. 
`EmployeeStores`. This would allow your schema to be scalable, employees can work in multiple stores.

In `SQL Server`:

```
CREATE TABLE EmployeeStores
(
   EMPLOYEEStoreID   INT IDENTITY,
   EMPLOYEEID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(employee_id),
   STOREID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Store(store_id)
)
```

Comment: You don't need an employee_listid. PK is employee_id,storeid.

Comment: @muehlbau PK of the new table would not be employee_id

Comment: @muehlbau - Employee_id and storeID are composite keys. You can still have EmployeeStoreID or EmployeeListID which would make it easier to find records in the new table. - This should not warrant a downvote as it is perfectly valid.

Comment: @popnoodles maybe my comment is not clear but it's eployee_id and store_id together.

Comment: @muehlbau - yes a composite key.  However you can still have EMPLOYEESTOREID to reference the table as the main identifier, just like EMPLOYEEID.

Comment: @DarrenDavies I don't say you can't have it but why introduce a new artificial key, waste space, and not just use the composite key? It does not make it easier to find records btw; working on core databases I can assure you that query optimizers often even profit from composite keys.

Comment: @muehlbau - depends entirely on how the internals handle it, you cannot guarentee that the execution plan will choose a composite key each time.  Plus, it's not a waste of space, what if I wanted to find the first ever entry in the database, how would I assume that with no datetime value? I could at least make an assumption based upon the new field introduced since it is an identity column.

Comment: @DarrenDavies yes, I cannot guarantee you that every query engine will profit from it - however you cannot say there is no waste of space (each entry in the list has an overhead of at least 4 Bytes for the artificial key). Your finding the first created value use case is an even worse use case: who says that the first entry is not deleted and a new entry is inserted with artificial key 1? My arguments come from a relational design point of view - sry for the downvote btw, that was a bit harsh, but I'm emotional when it comes to wrong assumptions in relational design.

Comment: @muehlbau - it is an identity column, SQL Server holds the seed so the column value will never be 1 again unless the DBA resets the identity manually for that table. I understand and respect your point of view, both answers are correct, I just prefer consistency (Since the OP is using artificial keys for Employee and Store tables) and IMO it is easier to find records using surrogate keys.